# Onsen UI Cordova Install Error

Tags: android, cordova, onsen-ui

I am trying to use **Onsen** for the first time following the instructions on the  get started page.

After downloading the template files to the project directory (gcsai) when using the **Cordova (5.4.1) command** (as admin) "cordova platform add android" I get the following **error.**

```
C:\Android\projects\gcsai>cordova platform add android
Adding android project...
Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Documents and Settings\USER\.cordova\l
ib\npm_cache\cordova-android\4.1.1\package\bin\create.bat" C:\Android\projects\g
csai\platforms\android io.onsen.helloworld "Onsen UI Project" --cli""
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

**My paths are**

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\db\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;

**My OS is Win XP SP3**

Not seeing a clear answer online after some time spent searching. can anyone offer a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by uninstalling **Cordova** and re-installing it by using

npm uninstall cordova

and then after a re-start I used the command

install -g cordova

Another problem remains with my set-up when trying to run the cordova emulate command but thats a different issue.

Jimmy